# Error Deploying SSAS Model. Failed to save modifications to the server. Error: The RoleMembership with the name of some GUID already exists

Tags: deployment, ssas, analysisservices

I've created a new SSAS tabular model by importing an existing one from the server, and modifying it. When I deploy it, I get the following error:

> Failed to save modifications to the server.
>   Error returned: The RoleMembership with the name of GUID goes here already exists in the Admin Role.

I've deleted and recreated the roles on the new model. I'm able to process the model locally.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to deploy the model after deleting the Admin role.
Then added it back, and deployed successfully again.